# Toggle isn't working for my jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so currently I have a program written where when you click a news `'.article'` headline, the `'.description'` pops down underneath and the headline is highlighted grey and all the other headlines to remain closed. Then, when you click another headline, the first one you clicked closes and the new one is highlighted and open. the javascript looks like this:

```
var main = function() {
$('.article').click(function() {
    $('.article').removeClass('current');
    $('.description').hide();

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).children('.description').toggle();
});

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Here is the the CSS for `'current'` looks like this:

```
.current .item {
 background: rgba(206,220,206,.9);
}
```

Now, my question is, I want the currently open article to *close* when you click it again. That's why I wrote the toggle command `$(this).children('.description').toggle();` instead of just `.show()`

**But it's not toggling...why?** It opens, but it won't close unless I click another article headline. I hope I've made sense in what I've written. This is my first attempt at learning javascript and I could use the help.

**full disclosure**: this is from codeacademy's lesson on building an interactive website but their Q/A didn't have the answer to my problem and apparently it's not monitored any longer because they are discontinuing this lesson.

**EDIT**: as requested, here is a sample of the HTML (it's really long so I didn't want to post the whole thing but I will if you want).

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="item row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
        <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you,

learninghowtocode

Comment: can you add all relevant code to OP...add html as well

Comment: _"and the headline is highlighted grey and all the other headlines to remain closed. Then, when you click another headline"_ How can "another headline" element be clicked if "all the other headlines to remain closed"? Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314, all the headlines show (one on top of the other). When I say the headline is _closed_ or _open_ I mean the article itself, but all the other headlines are still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `$('.description').hide();` hides ALL the `.description` elements then you toggle the current ones to show. You need to only hide the ones that are not children of the current article

Here is a simpler method (Based off Scott's answer, gotta love how we all push each other to be better ):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.article').on('click', function() {
    var $this=$(this).toggleClass('current'); 
    $('.article').not($this).removeClass('current');
  });
});
```

```css
.current .item {
  background: rgba(206, 220, 206, .9);
}
.article:not(.current) .description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
  <div class="item row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="description row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
      <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="item row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="description row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
      <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="article">
  <div class="item row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="description row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
      <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Original Answer:

The issue is that `$('.description').hide();` hides ALL the `.description` elements then you toggle the current ones to show. You need to only hide the ones that are not children of the current article with something like this:

`$('.article').not($(this)).find('.description').hide();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.article').click(function() {
    $('.article').removeClass('current');
     $('.article').not($(this)).find('.description').hide();
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).children('.description').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.article.current {
  background: rgba(206, 220, 206, .9);
}
.article:not(.current) .description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
    <div class="item row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
        <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="item row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
        <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="item row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
        <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This worked! thank you so much! I have two questions though...

1) why do you have to put the .find part of .find('.description').hide(). What does that do exactly?

2) I didn't change the CSS the way you said to and it still worked. Is that CSS just meant to highlight the not active articles as yellow?

Comment: I accidentally posted without the questions because I pressed enter. so I edited my post but here they are again. @DelightedD0D

1) why do you have to put the .find part of .find('.description'‌​).hide(). What does that do exactly? 2) I didn't change the CSS the way you said to and it still worked. Is that CSS just meant to highlight the not active articles as yellow?

Comment: Wow.. copied directly from my answer.. even left the comments in.. nice....

Comment: I added a better answer that borrows from Scotts answer but closes the descriptions for the non-clicked articles where his did not.   For your questions, 1) `$('.article').not($(this)).find('.description').hide();` ----- `$('.article').not($(this))` gets all elements with the `article` class *excluding the clicked article element* then `.find('.description')` gets all of the elements with the class `description` that are *children* of the article elements we got first. Finally `.hide()` hides all those elements.  2) ignore that yellow line, im a goober and left it in by mistake

Comment: @Scott, its not the same. Yours leaves all children  open when you click the next article, mine closes all other article descriptions when the new one opens. But yours did prompt me to change mine. Also, I was mentioning that in the comment above as you wrote that ;P

Comment: @Scott that +1 was me btw :)

Comment: oooooohhhh I get it! Thanks! :)

I "up-voted" and check-marked your answer

Answer (score 1):

Simplified.

You can merely toggle the class of the click element, no need to add and remove the same class. That's what `toggleClass()` is for.

Using a variable for the item to hide/show and using **CSS to hide** that class by default, is a bit more efficient. You don't have to wait for the DOM to load for things to hide.

```js
var main = function() {
$('.article').on('click',function() {
 var desc = $(this).children('.description');
    $(this).toggleClass('current'); //simple class toggle on click element
    $(desc).toggle();
});

};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.current .item {
 background: rgba(206,220,206,.9);
}

.description { display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
    <div class="item row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="source">AW Commercial Aviation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p class="title">CSeries Supplier Scramble</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p class="pubdate">Mar 22</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h1>CSeries Supplier Scramble</h1>
        <p>Three months before the planned first flight of its CSeries, Bombardier is grappling with supplier issues crucial to meeting its production cost...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good call on the class manipulation, though you should look closer before getting upset ;) + 1

Comment: @DelightedD0D never said i was "upset' .. just pointing out that yes, I noticed.